# Pinescript issue regarding making an alert hit one single time

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

**Strategy Code**

I have a pine code which sells and buys depending on moving average condition. The code are like:

```
study("MAS_Alerts")

qty = input(10000, "Buy quantity")


ma1 = input( "SMA",title="Select MA", options=["SMA", "EMA","TEMA", "WMA","HMA"])


len1 = input(7, minval=1, title="Period")

s=sma(close,len1)

e=ema(close,len1)


xEMA1 = ema(close, len1)
xEMA2 = ema(xEMA1, len1)
xEMA3 = ema(xEMA2, len1)
t = 3 * xEMA1 - 3 * xEMA2 + xEMA3


f_hma(_src, _length)=>
    _return = wma((2 * wma(_src, _length / 2)) - wma(_src, _length), round(sqrt(_length)))

h = f_hma(close, len1)

w = wma(close, len1)

ma = ma1 == "SMA" ? s : ma1 == "EMA" ? e : ma1 == "WMA" ? w : ma1 == "HMA" ? h : ma1 == "TEMA" ? t : na
```

**Alert Code**

Now here I am trying to make an alert feature out of the above code by adding further code which you can see below:

```
long_condition = 0
long_count = 1
green = color.green
red = color.red
if(s)
    if(long_count)
        long_count := long_count - 1
        if(s < close)
            long_condition := long_condition + 1
        else
            long_condition := long_condition - 1    

plot(long_condition, "Long", color=green)   

short_condition = 0
short_count = 1

if(s)
    if(short_count)
        short_count := short_count - 1
        if(s > close)
            short_condition := short_condition + 1
        else
            short_condition := short_condition - 1    

plot(short_condition, "Short", color=red)
```

I was planning to generate an alert for one time only whenever the condition mets for buy:

```
if(s)
    if(long_count)
        long_count := long_count - 1
        if(s < close)
            long_condition := long_condition + 1
        else
            long_condition := long_condition - 1    

plot(long_condition, "Long", color=green)
```

or for sell

```
if(s)
    if(short_count)
        short_count := short_count - 1
        if(s > close)
            short_condition := short_condition + 1
        else
            short_condition := short_condition - 1    

plot(short_condition, "Short", color=red)
```

Whenever one condition is met let suppose say, current price was higher than the SMA value: `if(s < close)` we will successfully make a long plot as it gets valid first. The **main issue now** why I had to write this post was that because price stays above the SMA for a long time depending on market trend my **Alert Code** keeps on firing the same long plot as many times the condition is valid. I just want to print a plot for alert either it is long or short just for one time and stop repeating it (I mean no double action if once a long plot has already been proceeded I don't want it to repeat until a new short plot condition `if(s > close)` is valid) and vise versa if once a short plot has already proceeded I don't want it to repeat the short plot alert again and until if a new long plot condition `if(s < close)` is valid. How can we make it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses `barssince()` to check eliminate consecutive entry signals:

```
//@version=4
study("MAS_Alerts2")

qty = input(10000, "Buy quantity")


ma1 = input( "SMA",title="Select MA", options=["SMA", "EMA","TEMA", "WMA","HMA"])


len1 = input(7, minval=1, title="Period")

s=sma(close,len1)

e=ema(close,len1)


xEMA1 = ema(close, len1)
xEMA2 = ema(xEMA1, len1)
xEMA3 = ema(xEMA2, len1)
t = 3 * xEMA1 - 3 * xEMA2 + xEMA3


f_hma(_src, _length)=>
    _return = wma((2 * wma(_src, _length / 2)) - wma(_src, _length), round(sqrt(_length)))

h = f_hma(close, len1)

w = wma(close, len1)

ma = ma1 == "SMA" ? s : ma1 == "EMA" ? e : ma1 == "WMA" ? w : ma1 == "HMA" ? h : ma1 == "TEMA" ? t : na
long_condition = 0
long_count = 1
green = color.green
red = color.red

long_trigger = s < close
short_trigger = s > close
b_since_long = barssince(long_trigger)[1]
b_since_short = barssince(short_trigger)[1]
if(s)
    if(long_count)
        long_count := long_count - 1
        if long_trigger and b_since_long > b_since_short
            long_condition := long_condition + 1
        else
            long_condition := long_condition - 1    

plot(long_condition, "Long", color=green)   

short_condition = 0
short_count = 1

if(s)
    if(short_count)
        short_count := short_count - 1
        if short_trigger and b_since_short > b_since_long
            short_condition := short_condition + 1
        else
            short_condition := short_condition - 1    

plot(short_condition, "Short", color=red)    
bgcolor(long_trigger ? color.green : short_trigger ? color.red : na)
plotchar(b_since_long, "b_since_long", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(b_since_short, "b_since_short", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

Yours above, the new version below:
[image]

Comment: That worked close to what I been trying sir but it seems it's working in 1sec only as I tried in different timeframe but it was alerting from a 1sec timeframe perspective. Is it possible so we can make it work around other timeframes like 5sec-1min-5min (anything)? I found it out very rapid and I want it if it can work slow which may eliminate bogus signals but I appreciate your work it did over than half percent of what I wished to do.

Comment: seems like and the code is written in such a way that it supporting SMA value '7' and 1sec and I would like to know if we can use different SMA value and timeframe by some code edit.

Comment: The code will run at any chart resolution, but when you create an alert, that alert will run on the chart's resolution at the time the alert was created. Our answer answers the question you asked. You can change the sma's period in the script's Inputs. Spending some time learning the basics of how to use indicators and alerts will be useful for you. We made your condition work the way your code was already setup, but there's lots of code in there that's not used. It will be up to you to decide what's useful or not.

Comment: ```b_since_long = barssince(long_trigger)[1]``` can you explain what this code did and I guess you called the barsince outside the if scope just so every time script run in a bar that function get called. I marked your answer as acceptance as it actually serves the question-answer. My bad I didn't change the input value of SMA earlier. Ya I am still not old coder in pine and will study more as you advice.

Comment: The two [`barssince()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_barssince) calls return the number of bars since the last condition occurred, as it was evaluated on the previous bar, because if we had used the current bar's value, i.e., without the `[1]`, it would return zero when calling it from a bar where the condition has just occurred. You can experiment by just plotting their values. You'll see how they behave on your charts. Welcome to Pine! This is the best place to start your journey: https://www.pinecoders.com/

Comment: bruh you have used barssince and I reckon this case scripts will be relying on a starting point which might lead to indicator repainting if I'm not wrong

Comment: Repainting issues are another matter altogether and weren't mentioned in your question. The use of `barssince()` by itself does not always entail repainting, and since in this case we are using the value of `barssince()` from the previous bar, it won't cause repainting. What will is the `long_trigger` for example, because it uses `close`. All you have to do to prevent that is the usual remedy of configuring your alert to trigger "Once Per Bar Close".